# Magento 2.2.7 single product image not showing on front end

Tags: magento2, theme, product-images, products, luma-theme

I'm developing a website in Magento 2.2.7. I have a problem whereby if I only add one image to a product in the admin area it doesn't show on the frontend, even after trying all of the various settings for that particular image, e.g: adding Thumbnail, Swatch, Base etc, and the checkbox to hide from product page isn't checked so it's not that.

The area for the image to display is there, but it's empty.

I don't get any errors when uploading images, and once an additional 2nd or more images are added then all are displayed in a carousel on the frontend.

Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: Can you replicate it on a vanilla instance? It sounds like a bug in theme customisation.